# Get download progress of a list of files

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-fs

I'm trying to get the download progress of a list of items in React Native. But in my current approach, the progress is not calculated correctly. I'm using [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) to download files.

```
const onPressDownload = async () => {
  const files = [
    'https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4',
    'https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_640_3MG.mp4',
    'https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_1280_10MG.mp4',
    'https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_1920_18MG.mp4',
    ... // This is a dynamic list
  ];

  const promises = [];
  let index = 1;
  let totalLength = 0;
  let downloadLength = 0;
  let progress = 0;

  for (const file of files) {
    const promise = RNFS.downloadFile({
      fromUrl: file,
      toFile: `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/download_${index}.mp4`,
      begin: (res) => { totalLength += res.contentLength; },
      progress: (res) => {
        downloadLength += res.bytesWritten;
        progress = (downloadLength / totalLength);
        console.log(progress);
      },
    });
    promises.push(promise);
    index++;
  }
  Promise.all(promises);
};
```

What I'm doing incorrectly here?

Answer (score 0):

-> You are doing it correct, But there is one common mistake which is as follows...

-> Insert await keyword before RNFS.downloadFile, Because it is asynchronous

-> Everything may work smoothly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).